# Bash: how to copy multiple files with same name to multiple folders

Tags: bash, copy, copy-paste

I am working on Linux machine.
I have a lot of files named the same, with a directory structure like this:

```
P45_input_foo/result.dat
P45_input_bar/result.dat
P45_input_tar/result.dat
P45_input_cool/result.dat ...
```

It is difficult to copy them one by one. I want to copy them into another folder named as `data` with similar folder names and file names:

```
/data/foo/result.dat
/data/bar/result.dat
/data/tar/result.dat
/data/cool/result.dat ...
```

In stead of copy them one by one what I should do?

Comment: Are you on a Linux or a Windows machine? You need a `bash` or `batch` solution?

Comment: @Inian I am working on linux machine. So I need a bash solution. Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a for loop in bash :

```
# we list every files following the pattern : ./<somedirname>/<any file>
# if you want to specify a format for the folders, you could change it here
# i.e. for your case you could write 'for f in P45*/*' to only match folders starting by P45 
for f in */*
do
    # we strip the path of the file from its filename
    # i.e. 'P45_input_foo/result.dat' will become 'P45_input_foo'
    newpath="${f%/*}"

    # mkdir -p /data/${newpath##*_} will create our new data structure
    # - /data/${newpath##*_} extract the last chain of character after a _, in our example, 'foo'
    # - mkdir -p will recursively create our structure
    # - cp "$f" "$_" will copy the file to our new directory. It will not launch if mkdir returns an error
    mkdir -p /data/${newpath##*_} && cp "$f" "$_"
done
```

the `${newpath##*_}` and `${f%/*}` usage are part of Bash string manipulation methods. You can read more about it [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+TheGeekStuff+(The+Geek+Stuff)).

Comment: thank you for your answer can you give more details? `{newpath##*_} "` seems weird to me

Comment: I dont know who vote me down. Can you help me to vote up? I didn't duplicate my question.

Comment: @Lbj_x: i did not downvote you, but whoever did it might have done so, because you did't show us any code that you attempted to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extract the 3rd item after "_" :

> P45_input_foo --> foo

create the directory (if needed) and copy the file to it. Something like this (not tested, might need editing):

```
 STARTING_DIR="/"
cd "$STARTING_DIR"
VAR=$(ls -1)
while read DIR; do
  TARGET_DIR=$(echo "$DIR" | cut -d'_' -f3)
  NEW_DIR="/data/$DIR"
  if [ ! -d "$NEW_DIR" ]; then
    mkdir "$NEW_DIR"
  fi
  cp "$DIR/result.dat" "$NEW_DIR/result.dat"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    echo "ERROR: encountered an error while copying"
  fi
done <<<"$VAR"
```

Explanation: assuming all the paths you've mentioned are under root `/` (if not change `STARTING_PATH` accordingly). With ls you get the list of the directories, store the output in `VAR`. Pass the content of `VAR` to the while loop.

Comment: Hi, may be I didn't explain it correctly. P45_* is one series of the PXX_* in one directory.

Comment: @Lbj_x Sorry. I still don't get what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: in the starting directory: I have P45_input_* series of folders. and P46_* and P47_* ect folders. I guess I need to specify the DIR in the beginning right?

Comment: @Lbj_x It doesn't matter. You just need to specify where the P45_*, P46_* ... are.  e.g. the files are in /test/P45_*, /test/P46_* ..., then STARTING_DIR="/test"

Comment: but the file that I want to copy is only at P45...I dont get where do you define DIR in your bash

Comment: Note: `if [ ! -d "$NEW_DIR" ]; then
    mkdir "$NEW_DIR";
  fi` can be shortened to `mkdir -p "$NEW_DIR"`

Comment: @anishsane good catch. I usually program in C. I tend to apply the same principles in bash. But good to know that there's a shorter way.

Comment: @Lbj_x `DIR` is 1 line stored in `VAR`. You read 1 line from `VAR` and assign it to `DIR`

Answer (score 1):

A bit of `find` and with a few `bash` tricks, the below script could do the trick for you. Remember to run the script without the `mv` and see if `"/data/"$folder"/"` is the actual path that you want to move the file(s).

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do

    fileNew="${file%/*}"       # Everything before the last '\'
    fileNew="${fileNew#*/}"    # Everything after the last '\'

    IFS="_" read _ _ folder <<<"$fileNew"

    mv -v "$file"  "/data/"$folder"/"

done < <(find . -type f -name "result.dat" -print0)
```